# Position absolute div's in a bootstrap col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to position divs absolute in a bootstrap col-

```
red{
    background-color:red;
}

.grid-item{
    position:relative;    
}

.about{
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}

.app{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
}
```

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nilssi/ah7m2k01/5/

The positions a good, but i would aspect a red background.

Comment: @CodeRomeos He has used it to on `.grid-item` div

Comment: @CodeRomeos.. Happens.. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `height` and `width` to `.red` you can see that `red color` gets applied:

```
.red{
    background-color:red;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ah7m2k01/6/)**